# Circular motion problem - is this solution correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Recently in my physics class, my instructor introduced this problem, yet I have some doubts about how to answer the question, as I believe it is missing some information. I have thought about the possibilities of the force the rocket applies, which are:

1.Perpendicular (both towards the center and outwards)

2.Parallel (both in the same direction as the velocity vector and opposite).

[image]

I have found 3 possible solutions, which of them is correct:
Force of thrust perpendicular to velocity and towards the center: For the 1st case, if the thrust was towards the center, then the centripetal force would equal the original gravitational force plus the force of thrust. Since velocity would not change, the rocket would move to an orbit with greater radius because of the increased centripetal force. This answer makes the most sense, because the object returns to the same radius.

Force of thrust parallel to velocity and in the same direction:
The velocity of the object would increase, but the gravitational force would remain the same, and since the gravitational force equals centripetal force, if the velocity increases the object would have to move on to an orbit with greater radius.

Force of thrust is parallel to velocity and in the opposite direction:
The velocity of the object would decrease, thus from $mv^2/r$, we can see that the current gravitational force is not able to accommodate this rocket at the current radius, so the object would move to a greater radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the angular momentum difference of the two orbits w.r.t. the planet. Obviously, the larger orbit has a greater angular momentum. This means there must be a net angular impulse when the thruster fires at point A; that is, the torque should be nonzero and should act to increase the angular momentum.

The answer should be evident from here.